# Login to asp.net mvc app using O365 credentials

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

Looking for a method of users logging into an application using their o365 credentials, is this possible? I've looked through the API's but can't find anything definitive but maybe I am looking in the wrong place?

If anyone could direct me to a link it would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your O365 login and window login are different?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean?

Comment: my be this will useful to you, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn OpenID authentication.
Take a look this implementations:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1033978/Office-Authentication-using-Visual-Studio-MVC-appl

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/authenticate-and-use-services

Comment: Really useful article. However, currently the app uses ASP.net individual user accounts as authentication and everything I have read seems to indicate that this can't be ran alongside O365 authentication? Do you know if this is accurate?

Comment: I have not work on O365 authentication yet. But in generel when you are working with any external idenity server (facebook, google, active directory ...) this should work.
I dont see how individual user accounts is problem. This is External authenication. You can (and probaly should) have both.